# SQL query results over two rows

Tags: sql-server

I managed to do this before but can't remember how and can't find an answer:
I'm trying to query a database for sum() and spread the results over 2 rows
e.g. sum(Men) as 'men', sum(Women) as 'women', sum(Men+women) as 'total'
New row
sum(men where age >45), sum(Women where age >45), sum(men + women over 45) as 'Total'
I'm sure this is simple but annoying me, please help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like.....

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age <=45 THEN MEN       ELSE 0 END) AS Men
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Age <=45 THEN WOMEN     ELSE 0 END) AS Women
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Age <=45 THEN Men+WOMEN ELSE 0 END) AS Total
      ,'45 or Under'                                     AS AgeGroup
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age > 45 THEN MEN       ELSE 0 END) AS Men
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Age > 45 THEN WOMEN     ELSE 0 END) AS Women
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Age > 45 THEN Men+WOMEN ELSE 0 END) AS Total
      ,'above 45'                                        AS AgeGroup
FROM Table
```

Or you could do something like.....

```
SELECT SUM(MEN)       AS Men
      ,SUM(WOMEN)     AS Women
      ,SUM(Men+WOMEN) AS Total
      ,'45 or Under'  AS AgeGroup
FROM Table WHERE Age <= 45
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(MEN)       AS Men
      ,SUM(WOMEN)     AS Women
      ,SUM(Men+WOMEN) AS Total
      ,'45 or Under'  AS AgeGroup
FROM Table WHERE Age > 45
```

Comment: Why not just put the predicate in the where clause, rather than scan the whole table twice? - `SELECT SUM(Men) AS Men, SUM(Women) AS Women, SUM(Men + Women) AS Total, '45 or Under' AS AgeGroup FROM Table WHERE Age <= 45 UNION ALL ...`

Comment: I was just looking at this query and thinking to myself, I think I might have over killed the query with these case statement :)

Comment: I think the best approach would probably be to create a values table and left join to main table and group by the rows in the values table to ensure two rows are returned whether they exist or not - but the question is vague enough for me to not be sure exactly what the end result should be!

Comment: @WayneB If this helps you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show others that this solved your problem. For more information you can also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)